# Resizing my swap partition on Debian encrypted lvm setup has disabled hibernate, how can I fix it?

Tags: debian, encryption, hibernate, lvm, swap

I installed Debian 11 on an ancient netbook, encrypted with a separate /home partition, otherwise accepting all the defaults.

Once I'd got the system set up I realized that I'd only got a 1GB swap partition, and 2GB of RAM, so I increased the size of the swap partition to 4GB (to make sure it always had enough swap to hibernate)

```
swapoff -a
lvextend --size +3G /dev/mapper/dell--mini--vg-swap_1 
mkswap /dev/mapper/dell--mini--vg-swap_1 
swapon -a
```

This worked suspiciously well, and free/htop confirmed that I now had 4GB of swap

But now when my system boots there are loads of errors about mdadm 'no arrays found in config file'.

And hibernate seems to work, but it won't resume.

What have I broken and how do I fix it?

---

It seems likely (thank you commenter!) that mkswap changed the UUID of the swap partition and that that needs to be updated so that resume can find it. Does anyone know how I do this?

Or possibly a cleaner way would be to redo the mkswap, forcing the UUID to be the same as the previous one, but again, where do I find the old UUID?

Comment: The mkswap command changed the UUID of the swap partition.  You need to update least two places with the new uuid so it can be found.

Comment: Thanks I figured it might be something like that, but how do I find out what the new UUID is, and where does it need changing?

Comment: mkswap prints the uuid, but you can also find it in /dev/disks/by*uuid and several tools can probe it as well.  You need to change it in the swap line in fstab and then https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240123/how-to-enable-the-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-20-04/ seems to cover the hibernation part.  I think the note there about the mkswap uuid being useless only applies to swap files.

Comment: Thanks very much for the crucial clues! I found the old UUID and redid the mkswap, which seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Posted the winning incantation as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that the problem was just that mkswap had changed the UUID of the swap file.

I found the old UUID with:

```
cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume 
RESUME=UUID=5caa6a65-ce03-4da5-aac2-9a9686c934d7
```

And then redid the mkswap command, forcing the original uuid:

```
swapoff -a
mkswap --uuid 5caa6a65-ce03-4da5-aac2-9a9686c934d7  /dev/mapper/dell--mini--vg-swap_1 
swapon -a
```

swap and hibernate now work fine.